# How do I automatically dedent code in vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, indentation, text-indent

I have a code similar to below open in vscode

```
def func():
    # Do something with about 24 lines
```

But then I feel like it would be better to remove my code from a function definition because of some problems ( which I assume do not matter at the moment).

Is there a way to remove the indents behind my lines of code or do I always have to dedent my code line by line.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Select the lines you want to dedent and shift+tab?

Comment: Thank you so much Sweeper. I didn't know it would be that easy. I was thinking that I would have to install an extension or something. Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

In VS-Code/In general
Just select the lines & use:

**De-Denting**
Shift ⇧ + Tab ↹

**Denting**
Tab ↹